# Unable to place ads between Recyclerview using firebase UI for fetching firestore data

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, ads, firebaseui

My AdapterClass

```
public class ShayariAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ShayariModel, ShayariAdapter.ShayariViewHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public ShayariAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ShayariModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShayariViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ShayariModel model) {
        holder.body.setText(model.getBody());
        holder.category.setText(model.getCategory());
        holder.author.setText(model.getAuthor());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ShayariViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shayari_card, parent, false);
        return new ShayariViewHolder(view);
    }


    class ShayariViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView body, author;
        TextView category;
        ImageView shareShayari;
        public ShayariViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shayariText);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorName);
            shareShayari = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareShayari);

            shareShayari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to add ads between recyclerview item as there are tutorials for simple adapter but can't find none for FirebaseUI Recyclerview adapter

I have tried google codelab tutorial but stuck in getItemViewType. Tried many things and stuck at this

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI doesn't allow you to change the data used to render the views.  It is just a very simple way to get started showing data from Firestore into a RecyclerView.  If you have a more advanced case where you need to add or modify the query results, you will need to build your own adapter.

Comment: So it means no for firebaseui, instead I have to use my own custom Recyclerview adapter

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yes.  FirebaseUI is open source, so you can copy from it.

Comment: But I am not that much proficient in Java yet, can you help me out ?